# How do I modify my addition and subtraction functions so that arrays can be passed as arguments using Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, addition

I'm working on an assignment where I have created two methods (add and subtract) that take parameters using the splatter method. I am trying to modify each method so that I can also pass arrays as parameters. I've tried using a conditional statement to check to see if my parameters are an array, but that did not work.

Here is my code:

```
class Math
def initialize 
    puts "Welcome to Math Dojo" 
    self    
end

def add (*nums)
    @sum = nums.reduce :+
    if nums == []
        nums.reduce :+
    puts "The sum is #{@sum}"
    self
end

def subtract (*nums)
    @diff = nums.reduce :-
    if nums == []
        nums.reduce :-
    end
    puts "The difference is #{@diff}"
    self
end
end
```

I need the code to pass the following tests:

```
challenge1 = Math.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2) # => 4
challenge2 = Math.new.add(1).add([3, 5, 7, 8], [2, 4.3, 1.25]).subtract([2,3], [1.1, 2.3])
challenge3 = Math.new.add(2, 5).subtract(9, 3, 5, 2)
```

The code will currently pass challenge1 and challenge3. How do I modify it to pass all three?

Comment: Please (edit to) explain in words what the "splatter method" is. You refer to the "following tests". In the first the desired result is shown to be `4`, but the desired results are not shown for the other two. Perhaps you could show the calculations (not code) involved in computing the result for, say, `Math.new.add(1,2).add([3, 4], [5,6]).subtract([7,8], [12,10])`, Is the first step to reduce that to `Math.new.add(3).add(7,11).subtract(-1, 2)`, then reduce that to `Math.new.add(3).add(18).subtract(-3)`, and finally obtain `18`? btw, Ruby has a built-in module `Math`.

Comment: "that did not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding arguments that are arrays, even if they are mixed with numbers, does not increase complexity as the arrays containing arrays and possibly numbers need only be flattened before obtaining totals.

```
class MyMath
  attr_reader :tot

  def initialize
    @tot = 0
  end

  def add(*obj)
    compute(*obj, :+)
  end

  def subtract(*obj)
    compute(*obj, :-)
  end

  def multiply(*obj)
    compute(*obj, :*)
  end

  def divide(*obj)
    compute(*obj, :/)
  end

  def compute(*obj, op)
    @tot = obj.flatten.reduce(@tot, op)
    self
  end
end
```

```
MyMath.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2).tot
  #=> 4
MyMath.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2).multiply(2, 4).tot
  #=> 32
MyMath.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2).divide(2.0, 4.0).tot
  #=> 0.5
MyMath.new.add(1).add([3, 5], [2, 4.3]).subtract([2,3], [1.1, 2.3]).tot
  #=> 6.9
MyMath.new.add(2, 5).subtract(9, [3, 5], 2).tot
  #=> -12
```

Comment: There's no need to use `public_send` if you already know the name of the method (`reduce`).

Comment: There's no need to use `send` or `__send__` either. You only need it if you don't know the method name. In your case, you know the name: `reduce`. You can just call it.

Comment: @Jörg, that's obvious! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. If you’re trying to determine if nums is an array, you would do `nums.is_a?(Array)`. `nums == []` checks if nums is an empty array.
2. `nums` is always an array. What you’re really trying to determine is if any of the elements inside `nums` is an array, and if so you want to reduce those. You either need to stop using reduce on `nums` (since it won’t work for arrays), or do the easier route and `flatten!` the array.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21

`flatten!` takes an array of arrays and turns it into a single array. It modifies the array in place as opposed to creating a new array, which means its more efficient than its `flatten` counterpart (which does have its place).

Check this out:

```
class Math
def initialize 
    puts "Welcome to Math Dojo" 
    self    
end

def add (*nums)
    nums.flatten!
    @sum = nums.reduce :+
    puts "The sum is #{@sum}"
    self
end

def subtract (*nums)
    nums.flatten!
    @diff = nums.reduce :-
    puts "The difference is #{@diff}"
    self
end
end
```